Sequalize Update a column on soft delete
in paranoid table,
Can I merge these two queries into one
  await activeSubscription.update({
    subscriptionStatus: constants.SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS.CANCELLED
  });

  await activeSubscription.destroy(); 

Basically I want to also set the status as cancelled, at the time of deleting the subscription.

Did you look at Sequelize hooks? It seems like the possible solution for you
